# mdl-lite dialog not displaying correct information

Tags: elm

I'm trying to make a list of buttons, each of which opens up a dialog which displays a different number. For example, the first button says '10' and then when it is clicked a dialog opens which also says '10'. The second says '20', and when it is clicked a dialog is opened that also says '20', etc. However, all of the dialogs say '10' when they are opened.

Here is the code:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html, div, text, p)
import Html.App as App exposing (program)
import Material
import Material.Button as Button
import Material.Scheme as Scheme
import Material.Dialog as Dialog


-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { buttons : List Int, mdl : Material.Model }


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( { buttons = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 ], mdl = Material.model }, Cmd.none )



-- MESSAGES


type Msg
    = Log Int
    | Mdl (Material.Msg Msg)



--VIEW


element : Int -> Model -> Html Msg
element int model =
    Dialog.view
        []
        [ Dialog.title [] [ text "Greetings" ]
        , Dialog.content []
            [ p [] [ text "What is this insanity?" ]
            , p [] [ text (toString int) ]
            ]
        , Dialog.actions []
            [ Button.render Mdl
                [ 0 ]
                model.mdl
                [ Dialog.closeOn "click" ]
                [ text "Close" ]
            ]
        ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        (List.map (\b -> button b model) model.buttons)
        |> Scheme.top


button : Int -> Model -> Html Msg
button int model =
    div []
        [ Button.render
            Mdl
            [ 1 ]
            model.mdl
            [ Button.raised
            , Button.ripple
            , Button.onClick (Log int)
            , Dialog.openOn "click"
            ]
            [ text (toString int) ]
        , element int model
        ]



-- UPDATE


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Log int ->
            let
                check =
                    Debug.log "Int" int
            in
                model ! []

        Mdl msg' ->
            Material.update msg' model



-- MAIN


main : Program Never
main =
    program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = always Sub.none
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I read mdl-lite only supports one dialog per application, so the problem must have been calling `element` multiple times. The solution is to call `element` once in the view function, and with each button click to update a `dialogInt` value in the `model`, and then to display this value in the dialog.

Here's the code:

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html, div, text, p)
import Html.App as App exposing (program)
import Material
import Material.Button as Button
import Material.Scheme as Scheme
import Material.Dialog as Dialog


-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { ints : List Int, dialogInt : Int, mdl : Material.Model }


init : ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init =
    ( { ints = [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70 ], dialogInt = 0, mdl = Material.model }, Cmd.none )



-- MESSAGES


type Msg
    = Log Int
    | UpdateDialogInt Int
    | Mdl (Material.Msg Msg)



--VIEW


element : Model -> Html Msg
element model =
    -- let
    --     check =
    --         Debug.log "int" int
    -- in
    Dialog.view
        []
        [ Dialog.title [] [ text "Greetings" ]
        , Dialog.content []
            [ p [] [ text "What is this insanity?" ]
            , p [] [ text (toString model.dialogInt) ]
            ]
        , Dialog.actions []
            [ Button.render Mdl
                [ 1 ]
                model.mdl
                [ Dialog.closeOn "click" ]
                [ text "Close" ]
            ]
        ]


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        ((element
            model
         )
            :: (List.map (\b -> button b model) model.ints)
        )
        |> Scheme.top


button : Int -> Model -> Html Msg
button int model =
    div []
        [ Button.render
            Mdl
            [ int ]
            model.mdl
            [ Button.raised
            , Button.ripple
            , Button.onClick (UpdateDialogInt int)
            , Dialog.openOn "click"
            ]
            [ text (toString int) ]
        ]



-- UPDATE


update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Log int ->
            let
                check =
                    Debug.log "int" int
            in
                model ! []

        UpdateDialogInt int ->
            { model | dialogInt = int } ! []

        Mdl msg' ->
            let
                check =
                    Debug.log "msg" msg'
            in
                Material.update msg' model



-- MAIN


main : Program Never
main =
    program
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = always Sub.none
        }
```